# How to deploy a pre-built next.js app to Vercel (without Git integration)?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I am really looking for a (simple, straightforward) way to deploy a next.js application from an existing, private Gitlab repository and finished build pipeline to Vercel, but without uploading my sources or running builds on their systems; just the previously "built" next.js bundle.

Besides their popular repository integrations, which don't fit here, they also offer a [CLI tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/client) and an [HTTP API](https://vercel.com/docs/api) for manual publishing.

The CLI tool, however, seems to push the whole repository to Vercel as well and won't deploy anything unless build-time information like "command to install modules" etc. is provided.

The API is well-documented, but I guess it works the same way, and I couldn't find an example that explains which files I need to select for the upload (which requires a "list" of files).

Comment: Hey! Lee from Vercel here. Could you share more about why this - are you concerned with repo access?

Comment: Hello @leerob, correct, the code is proprietary and there is already a full CI/CD in place which generates the next app, so the last missing bit is really just to deploy it to Vercel from there (preferably through a CLI tool)

Comment: It's currently not possible to do this. It is on our roadmap, however. Please contact our support team to talk more about your requirements! https://vercel.com/contact

Comment: @leerob +1 for that. I have a complex CI/CD pipeline and it is a huge pain to integrate it with Vercel right now. First I build my app in the pipeline before testing, and then it is built again at Vercel. And I have to duplicate all required ENV variables for both envionments. What I really need is a CLI command that uploads the prebuilt app and starts it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a two step process in their docs, one call to `POST /v2/now/files` uploads the assets and then `POST /v12/now/deployments` to create the deployment from those assets.

Just run an async function in your build pipeline with a couple await calls to Vercel and you should be set. Super simplified example but if you build the client and handlers, it should look like this more or less I'd think:

```js
// Assumes you put together a Vercel REST client and used the above endpoints
import { vercelClient } from '../lib/clients'
import { postFiles, createDeployment } from '../lib/handlers'

async function deployToVercel(files) {
  let errors 
  await postFiles({ payload: files }).catch(err => { errors = err }
  await createDeployment({ moreSettings: here }).catch(err => { errors = err }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but which `files` should be uploaded from the next build output?

Comment: Run `next export` - see more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Comment: That only works for fully static "applications"

Answer (score 6):

You could also create a **new project** using a **temporary repository** – it can be some blank repo on GitHub, for example.

After the project exists, you can disconnect the Git repo, change the *Framework preset* and set up a CI pipeline to publish a pre-built/static HTML site there.

*(I also find it strange that it's not possible to create a "blank" project via their web UI.)*

Comment: can you provide an example of the CI Pipeline using Github actions?